# Why will it say Invalid left-hand side in assignment?

Tags: javascript, html

So, recently I was making a project while i found this error. It says Invalid left-hand side in assignment. This is my HTML:

```
<section><input type="button" value="Activate radar jamming" onclick="jam()"></section>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
function jam() {
    document.getElementById("jam")=Math.random();
    if(jam < 0.350) {
       console.log(jam)
       location.reload();
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: use `document.getElementById("jam").value =Math.random();`

Comment: What do you expect `document.getElementById("jam")=Math.random();` to do?

Comment: document.getElementById("jam").value=Math.random();

Comment: Please take the time to use proper code indentation. Also, note that your quoted code is missing a `}` (at least).

Answer (score 1):

> Why will it say Invalid left-hand side in assignment?

Because the left-hand side of an assignment can't be a function call. It must be a variable or property.

Your `jam` function also has issues. You're assigning to the symbol `jam`, but you're not declaring that as a variable in the function, and so what you're assigning to is actually the function itself (because it's called `jam`).

Fixing both issues:

```
function jam() {
    var jamValue = Math.random();                    // Note the variable
    document.getElementById("jam").value = jamValue; // Note the .value
    if(jamValue < 0.350) {
        console.log(jamValue)
        location.reload(); // It's unclear to me whether this should be in the `if`
    }
}
```

That assumes the element with the `id` `"jam"` is an `input` element. If not, change `.value` to `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Set random value to element 'value' :

```
document.getElementById("jam").value = Math.random();
```